# jQuery From plugin: file not submitted if upload is triggered by control other than file input

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, file-upload, jquery-forms-plugin

I've got a button which should initiate file upload. I've placed file input and that button on the same form.  I use jQuery Form plugin to upload the file:

```
    $("#file").change(function (event) {
        $(this).closest("form").ajaxSubmit({
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSubmit: function(formData, form, options) {
                /* show activity indicator */
            },
            success: function(response, statusText, xhr, form) {
                /* process results */
            },
            error: function() {
                /* handle error */
            }
        });
    });

    $("#thebutton").click(function() {
        $("#file").click();
    });
```

I'm debugging on server side.

If I use file input to choose a file (by clicking Browse button) file is submitted and everything is just fine.

However if I click `#thebutton` and choose the file, the file on server side is null (although other fields of the form are submitted as usually).

What can you suggest?